# I want to hide URL shown in taskbar on mousehover on hyperlink

Tags: html

Suppose i have anchor tag

LInk

When i mouse hover the anchor page url will be shown at the bottom of the browser.
I want to hide it completely. can you please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a jquery code that should works:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').click(function(){
         $(this).attr({href: "#myanchor"});
    });
});
```

this will set the href attribute AND go to your anchor at the same time